# Cognos 10.1 Frameowrk Manager get automatically updated if there is any change in Database

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

For eg. I have created a project in Framework manager based on a Database. I have created Report also based on this FM.
Now after some time if any changes come in my database(Updation).
Is it possible to automically update FM as Database data changes or update
Some script or method is there through which we can acheive this?????
Upto what extent we can update or modify automatically.
Please give me some soluiton....

Answer (score 1):

If data is simply updated in your DB tables — you don't have to do anything, Cognos will pickup changes next time you run the report. There's a caching level, so if you want “real-time” data — turn Local Cache of on Query level in the reports.

If you want to update FM model structure when a new column / table appears — you can generate XML update scripts (they're human-readable) and run BMTScriptPlayer to apply changes to your model / package.

Some links on updating FM models:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21335529
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/0a7c97bb-6cf9-4ddb-a918-80994e7b444d/entry/framework_manager_automation6?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way to automatically do it. However, I have seen a program written to help with cases where attributes or dimensions are added. It will require some sort of meta-data table in the database which contains the new/changed columns. A program must then be written to read the model.xml file (can be written in any language, but something like Java or Python has tons of built in XML parsing methods), compare it against said meta-data table, and change the model. Publishing was then done via SDK calls. The program I saw was needed as it was an OEM product where Cognos was used on top of a 5NF database. Really complex to write, and technically still wasn't fully automated.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if a column is removed or renamed? What happens if a table's cardinality changes? You need a human to do this stuff. If you need to constantly add columns to a FM model it implies there may be a design issue (i.e. crosstabbing data in a table)